# How Can I Use UISlider to cycle through an UIImageView image sequence to create an animated effect

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimageview, uislider

For the app i am currently working on i am trying to take a series of images and link them to a UISlider. Interacting with the slider will create an animated effect, cycling through the frames. I have been able to create a standalone animation from the series of images, however i am not too certain about how to add the UISlider and make the appropriate links to achieve the desired effect.

Here is what i have so far...

```
- (void) viewDidLoad{
```

//---Animate Images Array----
/*

```
NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame1.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame2.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame3.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame4.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame5.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame6.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame7.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame8.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame9.png"],
                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame10.png"],
                   nil];

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,44,703,704); 
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; 
imageView.animationImages = images; 
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;


imageView.animationDuration = 4;
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[imageView startAnimating];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:imageView cache:YES];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];


[imageView release];
[super viewDidLoad];
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get a `UISlider` object to work with `animationImages` property of an `UIImageView`. However you can maintain an array of `UIImage`s and then set the `UIImageView` object's `image` property. For this you will have to set an action for the `UIControlEventValueChanged` event. Set the max value of the slider to the number of images i.e. `[imageArray count]` and then based on the current value of the slider, update the image.

```
- (void)valueChanged:(UISlider *)slider {
    NSInteger currentImageIndex = lroundf(slider.value);
    imageView.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:currentImageIndex];

    [slider setValue:roundf(slider.value) animated:YES];
}
```